# sar: enable data collecting

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring, arch-linux, sar

I've just installed the `sysstat` package on Manjaro. When running  `sar` for the first time I see:

```
Cannot open /var/log/sa/sa21: No such file or directory
Please check if data collecting is enabled
```

How do I check whether data collecting is enabled?

If it's not, how would I go about enabling it?

Answer (score 19):

On Ubuntu 16.04 I just ran into this same issue. After some [grousing](https://www.crybit.com/sysstat-sar-on-ubuntu-debian/) around I found I needed to enable the service by editing the file `/etc/default/sysstat`

Change `ENABLED="false"` to true:

```
# Should sadc collect system activity informations? Valid values
# are "true" and "false". Please do not put other values, they
# will be overwritten by debconf!
ENABLED="true"
```

Restart the service:

```
systemctl restart sysstat.service
```

Just a quick note, like a dingleberry I wasn't reading closely enough and navigated to `/etc/sysstat/sysstat` instead of `/etc/default/sysstat` and wasted 5 minutes poking around the man page and stuff.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!  The above didn't work for me. (Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 11):

The `sysstat` service and associated timers need to be started:

```
systemctl start  sysstat sysstat-collect.timer sysstat-summary.timer
```

To auto-start on next system startup:

```
systemctl enable sysstat sysstat-collect.timer sysstat-summary.timer
```

Comment: If you do not reboot, you also have to start the two timers `sysstat-collect.timer` and `sysstat-summary.timer` which are mentioned in the `[Install]` section of `sysstat.service`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this would be run by cron or as a service depending on how the package for your system configures it.  Modern versions use `sa1` to collect the historical data to files.  Older versions ran `atsar` to do the same.

Check the `man` pages starting with `man sar`.  Also there should be documentation in `/usr/share/doc/sysstat`.

`sar` can be used to collect and display current data even if the historical data is not available.

Check to see if there are any files in `/var/log/sa`, If there are then data is being collected.

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS7, after the `sysstat` package is installed, the sysstat service is not running :

```bash
$ sar
Cannot open /var/log/sa/sa07: No such file or directory
$ systemctl status sysstat
* sysstat.service - Resets System Activity Logs
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysstat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

You have to start it :

```bash
$ sudo systemctl start sysstat
$ systemctl status sysstat
* sysstat.service - Resets System Activity Logs
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysstat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2022-07-07 17:24:20 CEST; 1s ago
  Process: 93293 ExecStart=/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 --boot (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 93293 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 07 17:24:20 PAR-SCAL-CONNECT02 systemd[1]: Starting Resets System Activity Logs...
Jul 07 17:24:20 PAR-SCAL-CONNECT02 systemd[1]: Started Resets System Activity Logs.
```

And now it works fine :

```bash
# sar
Linux 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 (HOSTNAME-OF-SERVER)  07/07/22        _x86_64_        (4 CPU)
    
17:24:20          LINUX RESTART
#
```

On Ubuntu, after the `sysstat` package is installed, you have to enable it :

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure sysstat
```